# Reset v-model without updating its dependent variables

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, v-model

I have `<input>` fields like

```
<input type="text" v-model=user.name" />
<input type="text" v-model="user.phone" />
<button @click="add">add user</button>
```

whenever I click on `add user`, it should push the `user` to `users` array and clear the `v-model` (in order to push more users). My `add()` method looks as below.

```
add()
{
  this.users.push( this.user );
  this.user.name = '';
  this.user.phone = '';
}
```

However after resetting the `user` `v-model`, the element in the `users` array is also turning into empty string. How can I reset the `v-model` without changing the data in the `users` array?

Comment: The behavior you describe doesn't happen with the code you posted. Are you simplifying a more complicated scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way is just to reset the whole `user` object instead of property by property:

```
add()
{
  this.users.push( this.user );
  this.user = {name: '', phone: ''};
}
```

Demo:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    user: {name: '', phone: ''},
    users: []
  },
  methods: {
    add() {
      this.users.push(this.user);
      this.user = {name: '', phone: ''};
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  name: <input type="text" v-model="user.name" /><br>
  phone: <input type="text" v-model="user.phone" /><br>
  <button @click="add">add user</button>
  <hr>
  users: {{ users }}
</div>
```

> Why did it not work?

Because when you do:

```
this.users.push( this.user );
// this changes the name of the user that happens to be inside the users array
this.user.name = '';
```

You are adding the `this.user` into the `this.users` array. If you change it later, like `this.user.name = 'something';`, you are changing the same object (that is now inside `this.users` array too).

On the other hand, when overwrite it, it is a new object:

```
this.users.push(this.user);
this.user = {name: '', phone: ''};
// the line above makes `this.user` point to (reference) a new object.
// the object that was pushed into the array still exists, but this.user does not point to it anymore
// the line below sets the name of the user created in the line above, not the previous (that is in the array)
this.user.name = 'bob';
```

---

Alternative: Cloning.

If you wanted to follow this path, you'd have some alternatives. From "manual" cloning:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    user: {name: '', phone: ''},
    users: []
  },
  methods: {
    add() {
      this.users.push({name: this.user.name, phone: this.user.phone});
      this.user.name = '';
      this.user.phone = '';
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  name: <input type="text" v-model="user.name" /><br>
  phone: <input type="text" v-model="user.phone" /><br>
  <button @click="add">add user</button>
  <hr>
  users: {{ users }}
</div>
```

To deep cloning:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    user: {name: '', phone: ''},
    users: []
  },
  methods: {
    add() {
      let userDeepClone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.user));
      this.users.push(userDeepClone);
      this.user.name = '';
      this.user.phone = '';
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  name: <input type="text" v-model="user.name" /><br>
  phone: <input type="text" v-model="user.phone" /><br>
  <button @click="add">add user</button>
  <hr>
  users: {{ users }}
</div>
```

To shallow cloning:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    user: {name: '', phone: ''},
    users: []
  },
  methods: {
    add() {
      let userShallowClone = {...this.user}; // or Object.assign({}, this.user);
      this.users.push(userShallowClone);
      this.user.name = '';
      this.user.phone = '';
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  name: <input type="text" v-model="user.name" /><br>
  phone: <input type="text" v-model="user.phone" /><br>
  <button @click="add">add user</button>
  <hr>
  users: {{ users }}
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks It worked. can you explain why resetting property by property did not work since both does the same?